# JSTL: "Empty" check Bug? Need a fix

Tags: java, jstl

I'm trying to use JSTL's empty operator to check if an object is NULL or not and output some html accordingly, but it seems to always return true regardless. So either I've misunderstood how to implement this (which is quite possible) or there is some bug here. Either way I need a working solution.. if not by JSTL, then by some other means. Here is the code:

```
<%@page import="com.ksc.models.UserToken"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%
    UserToken token = (UserToken)session.getAttribute("userToken");
    if (token != null) {
        System.out.println("***** Token: " + token.toString());
    }
%>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="/KSC" class="brand">KSC Technology &amp; Sciences</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${empty token}">
                                    <li><a href="/KSC/account/login">Login</a></li>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                            <b class="icon-user"></b>
                                            Account
                                            <b class="caret"></b>
                                        </a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="/KSC/account/my-account">My Account</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/KSC/account/logout">Logout</a></li>
                                            <c:if test="${token.hasRole('Administrators')}">
                                                <li><a href="/KSC/admin">Dashboard</a></li>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, I want to output a "login" link when the user is not logged in or logout link when the user is logged in. The code at the top which prints the token proves to me that the object is not always null. I have in fact seen the output window give me this:

`INFO: ***** Token: com.ksc.models.UserToken@72087294`

and yet the UI is always displaying the login link even when I'm already authenticated. So, what gives?

**EDIT**

I edited the code a bit and an now starting to wonder if there's something else going on here.. here is my code:

```
<%@page import="com.ksc.models.UserToken"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%
    UserToken token = (UserToken)session.getAttribute("userToken");

    boolean authorized = (token != null);

    if (authorized) {
        System.out.println("***** Auth Token: " + token.toString());
    }
%>

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="/KSC" class="brand">KSC Technology &amp; Sciences</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <c:if test="${not authorized}">
                            <li><a href="/KSC/account/login">Login</a></li>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${authorized}">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                    <b class="icon-user"></b>
                                    Account
                                    <b class="caret"></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="/KSC/account/my-account">My Account</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/KSC/account/logout">Logout</a></li>
                                    <c:if test="${token.hasRole('Administrators')}">
                                        <li><a href="/KSC/admin">Dashboard</a></li>
                                    </c:if>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </c:if>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm pretty certain that is supposed to be working. This code is everything inside of a single jsp page which is then placed into a normal page with a `<jsp:include>` tag. Furthermore, I am using Spring MVC. Could either one of these facts (or both) cause this problem? It's strange because I still see the output window displaying the fact that the auth token is there. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added it to the ModelMap in my controller method and then used it like this:

`<c:if test="${userToken == null}">`

AND

`<c:if test="${userToken != null}">`

It now works, but I would still like to know why the other way didn't work.. very confusing...